# Why do tetrahedral complexes have approximately 4/9 the field split of octahedral complexes?

Tags: energy, orbitals, coordination-compounds

I am trying to calculate the relationship between the octahedral field splitting parameter ($\Delta_\mathrm{o}$) and the square planar field splitting parameter ($\Delta_\mathrm{sp}$) and thought a good way to start would be to understand why $\Delta_\mathrm{t}=4/9\Delta_\mathrm{o}$ for tetrahedral fields but couldn't find any information on it.

How does one arrive at this particular ratio mathematically?

Comment: Related: [Why do octahedral metal ligand complexes have greater splitting than tetrahedral complexes?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42257/7951)

Comment: I decided to edit and vote for reopening. The linked duplicate asks *why* one is greater than the other, this one asks about the numerical difference and how it is derived.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ratio is derived in [The angular overlap model. How to use it and why](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed051p633) J. Chem. Educ., vol. 51, page 633-640.

First, relative expressions ([Shaffer Angular Overlap Factors](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/24/2/0361/)) are derived for overlap integrals between metal and ligand orbitals as a function of angles.

For ligand sigma orbitals, the expressions are a functions of 2 angles, specifying the direction of the ligands in the coordinate system of the metal.

For pi-x and pi-y ligand orbits, there is a third angle for orientation about the ligand-metal axis.

Then, assuming the ligand-metal distances are the same in both the tetrahedral and octahedral cases, and considering the coordinate geometry of the ligands in the two cases, the relationship:

$$\Delta_{T} = -4/9 \Delta_{O}$$

is obtained.

For another discussion of this ratio in the framework of the angular overlap model, as well as extension to other geometries such as square planar, see [A New Look at Structure and Bonding in Transition Metal Complexes](https://books.google.com/books?id=5D-C9Z1IPrMC&pg=PA123&dq=%22derivation%22%20%224/9%22%20octahedral%20tetrahedral&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK44qV3MPPAhVTgiYKHfdWDaEQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22derivation%22%20%224%2F9%22%20octahedral%20tetrahedral&f=false), *Advances in Inorganic Chemistry and Radiochemistry*, Volume 21, pages 113-146.